# How to control the function order in edoc file?

Tags: erlang, edoc

i want to generate the edoc file for one erlang module, here is my code http://ideone.com/TFktht,

I want oder the export api interface, but i can not success.

```
generate_log_statistics/4   Analyse the log files and draw graph.
prepare_sipp_cmd/3  Shows SIPp online help documentation of what config parameters there are.
prepare_systeminfo_filenames/1  Prepare the log files according which blades you want to monitor.
run_scenario/6  Run the SIPp scenario.
start_collect_system_infos/1    Start collecting the logs.
stop_collect_system_infos/1 Stop collecting the logs.
```

These exported api in edoc are not odered.
I want:

```
prepare_sipp_cmd/3
prepare_systeminfo_filenames/1
start_collect_system_infos/1 
run_scenario/6
start_collect_system_infos/1 
generate_log_statistics/4
```

Answer (score 2):

#### To order functions

Put this in your rebar.config:

```
{edoc_opts, [{sort_functions, true}]}.
```

Or you can generate single doc files with something like:

```
edoc:file("src/foo.erl", [{dir, "doc"}, {sort_functions, true}]).
```

"doc" being the output directory.

#### To achieve specific order

Turn off function sorting, as above, but with `{sort_functions, false}` and order the functions in your source as required.

Comment: I don't use rebar, just the source file, i use this command: `edoc:files(["sbgEstSupport.erl"], [{sort_functions, false}]).`, but it can no be worked.

Comment: `edoc:files(["sbgEstSupport.erl"], [{dir, "."}, {sort_functions, false}]).`